# Plot 3d plane from x+y+z=6 equation in plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I have a set of equations (z1) x+y+z=6, (z2) x+2y+2z=9 and (z3) x+3y+4z=13 and would like to plot the planes using plotly.

**Method1: using mesh3d**

```
require(plotly)

x<-seq(from=-10, to=10, by=1)
y<-seq(from=-10, to=10, by=1)
z1<-6-x-y #For the first plane

fig <- plot_ly(x = ~, y = ~y, z = ~z1, type = 'mesh3d')
fig
```

Produces no output though. Why?

**Method 2: Using surface**

Whereas this produces a plane but the wrong one.

```
library(plotly)

x<-seq(from=-10,to=10,by=1)
y<-seq(from=-10,to=10,by=1)

z1<-6-x-y
z1<-matrix(rep(z1,10),NROW(x),10)

fig <- plot_ly(showscale = FALSE)
fig <- fig %>% add_surface(z = ~z1)
fig
```

This plane is not correct. If you look at the point x=2, y=2, z should equal 2 but it doesn't. Instead it is 22, and that's not correct.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `x <- seq(from=-10, to=10, by=1); y<-seq(from=-10, to=10, by=1)`, x+y+z=6 is not plane but line.
You need to prepare more data points.

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr); library(plotly)

x <- seq(from=-10, to=10, by=1)
y <- seq(from=-10, to=10, by=1)
z1 <- 6-x-y #For the first plane

origin <- tibble(x = x, y = y, z = z1)
# prepare all combination of x and y, and calculate z1
xyz1 <- tidyr::crossing(x, y) %>%
  mutate(z1 = 6-x-y)

plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z1, type = "mesh3d", data = xyz1) %>% 
  add_markers(~ x, ~y, ~z1, data = origin)
```

Orange points are the data you prepare (when `x <- seq(from=-10, to=10, by=1); y<-seq(from=-10, to=10, by=1)` , x+y+z=6 is line.)
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick help. Why is it not an equation of a plane?

Comment: @HCAI `x+y+z=6` is an equation of a plane

Comment: @DerekO; @HCAI; Sorry for not explaining enough.  I modified my answer.